# Reload a Modal With New Data Each Time It is Opened

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView that displays a list of results from a database query. I have a button in each row that corresponds to that result's id. When you click this button, the database is queried for extra details relating to that result and displays them in a modal.

This works properly the first time I click one of the results, but with subsequent clicks the modal will not update with the new data. How can I force the modal to reload each time it is to be opened?

Relevant code

Data Button In Main Page

```
<asp:ImageButton 
runat="server"
ID="imgbtnView"
ToolTip="View"
AlternateText="View"
ImageUrl='~/images/view.gif'
OnCommand="ViewOrderModal"
CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Order_ID") %>'
/>
```

Code Behind for Main Page

```
public void ViewOrderModal(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{    
    Session["Order_ID"] = e.CommandName;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showModal", "showModal()", true); 
}
```

Code Behind for Modal

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Order_ID"] == null)
        {
            Session["Order_ID"] = "";
        }
    }
    SetOrder();
    UpdateInfo();

}

private void SetOrder()
{
    Order_ID = Session["Order_ID"].ToString();
    // make sql query to get order
}

private void UpdateInfo()
{
    //Set fields in Modal tags equal to database results
}
```

Comment: You need to call `SetOrder` and `UpdateInfo` from `ViewOrderModal`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev would you please be able to provide an example on how to do so properly? `SetOrder` and `UpdateInfo` are in `OrderModal.ascx.cs` and `ViewOrderModal` is in `OrderGrid.ascx.cs`. I've tried to do as you've suggested previously, but havens been able to get it to work; it stops my scripts from displaying the modal for some reason

Comment: The same way you do it from `OnLoad`. And put the two calls into `if(!IsPostback){...}`

Comment: darn, still doesn't want to update properly :(